# Running multiple Docker containers on OSX in separate codebases

Tags: docker

I have a Laravel project and I made a Docker environment (using Docker Compose) which has the following:

- app (php-fpm and nginx) -- exposes port 80:80
- mysql -- exposes port 3306:3006
- redis

They're all linked on a network called `my-net`

Now, I also have a separate github repo called `admin`, which is an admin panel in ReactJS.  The ReactJS project uses the Laravel project as a backend (uses routes in the admin namespace)

So in this project, I want to setup a Dockerfile as well, but I want it to have access to the Laravel project's network (`my-net`).  How is this achieved?  Obviously, it seems that the `admin` project's Dockerfile cannot refer to `my-net`, because it doesn't know it exists.  Should I just be routing requests via the "public" and hit `localhost:80/admin/x/y/z`?  Or is there an internal-network way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hit `localhost` because it is simply wrong (localhost for a docker container is not your host's address, but container's address).

That said, you can use a network created with compose with a standard docker container. What you are missing is that the network is not called `my-net` as you expect but something like `<folder name>-my-net` where `<folder name>` is the folder where your docker-compose.yml file is located.

To find the correct name of the network to be used you can run `docker network ls`.

As an alternative, you could create a network manually with `docker network create mynet` and declare it as external in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  srvc:
    ...
    networks:
    - mynet
  ...
networks:
  mynet:
    external:
      name: mynet
```

Comment: hm, i've been hitting localhost:80 for my laravel project just fine.  That's because I'm exposing port 80 like I said above, no?

Comment: From another container or from your host?

Comment: no from the browser.  I didn't realize that you were referring to another container when you said

Comment: Yeah it works from the host networking but your  reactjs container wouldn't be able to reach your backend container on `localhost`